# Unstack columns by groups in parallel with polars

Tags: python-polars

Hy!

I need to unstack some columns in polars, but i want to group the columns by column 'a'

```
seq_ = df['a'].unique()
l = len(seq_)
dfs = []

for idx, a in enumerate(seq_):
    df_tmp = df.filter(pl.col('a') == a)
    steps = df_tmp.shape[0]
    df_tmp = df_tmp.unstack(step=steps, how="horizontal",columns=['b', 'c'])
    df_tmp = df_tmp.with_columns(pl.lit(a).alias('a'))
    dfs.append(df_tmp)

df_tmp = pl.concat(dfs, how='diagonal')
```

this code is too much slower.
Is there any way to do this in polars more faster?

from this:

```
┌─────┬───────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆  b    ┆ c    │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ a     ┆ f    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ b     ┆ g    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ c     ┆ h    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ d     ┆ i    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ e     ┆ j    │
└─────┴───────┴──────┘
```

to this:

```
┌─────┬───────┬──────┬─────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆  b_0  ┆  b_1 ┆ b_2 ┆ c_0  ┆ c_1  ┆ c_2  │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │ 
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str  ┆ str ┆ str  ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════╪═════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ a     ┆ c    ┆ d   ┆ f    ┆ h    ┆  i   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ b     ┆ e    ┆null ┆ g    ┆ j    ┆ null │
└─────┴───────┴──────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: The other solutions are performant but it may also be useful to know your current approach could be written as `pl.concat((df.unstack(1) for df in df.partition_by("a")), how="diagonal")` (you could then fix/drop the extra `a_*` columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A `group_by` with `all` aggregation will transform the `b` and `c` columns into lists.
- From there, With `list.to_struct()`, you can name each element with a custom field name, and it will be padded out with `null`s at this time per row. (The reason there's `df = ...` steps below instead of all in one step is due to the way `fields` works when passing in a late-binding lambda, run into duplicate field issues)
- `unnest` makes each `field` of a `struct` column its own column.

```py
df = df.group_by('a', maintain_order=True).all()

for col in 'bc':
    df = df.with_columns(
        pl.col(col).list.to_struct(
            n_field_strategy='max_width', fields=lambda i: f'{col}_{i}'
        )
    ).unnest(col)
```

```
shape: (2, 7)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b_0 ┆ b_1 ┆ b_2  ┆ c_0 ┆ c_1 ┆ c_2  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str ┆ str ┆ str  ┆ str ┆ str ┆ str  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ a   ┆ c   ┆ d    ┆ f   ┆ h   ┆ i    │
│ 2   ┆ b   ┆ e   ┆ null ┆ g   ┆ j   ┆ null │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
```

There might be an alternate, cleaner solution with `pivot`, but at a glance I don't think this quite fits the mold of a `pivot`.

Comment: Bro, thank you very much, you saved my life, seriously, I was already out of my brains to think hahah
I'm going to study the struct and unnest to understand better, but that's exactly what I wanted.

My execution time on the dataframe went from 1:40h to 2 seconds, thakyouuuuuu S2

Comment: if you define the lambda as `lambda i, col=col: f'{col}_{i}'` then that fixes the late-binding lambda issue so that you don't have to keep setting df for each column.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach using melt/pivot could look like this:

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        i=pl.int_range(0,pl.count()).over('a')
    )
    .melt(['a','i'])
    .with_columns(variable=pl.col('variable')+pl.lit("_")+pl.col('i').cast(pl.Utf8))
    .pivot('value', 'a','variable','first')
)
shape: (2, 7)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b_0 ┆ b_1 ┆ b_2  ┆ c_0 ┆ c_1 ┆ c_2  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str ┆ str ┆ str  ┆ str ┆ str ┆ str  │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ a   ┆ c   ┆ d    ┆ f   ┆ h   ┆ i    │
│ 2   ┆ b   ┆ e   ┆ null ┆ g   ┆ j   ┆ null │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘
```